# Using sed in a Makefile

Tags: unix, sed, makefile

I'm trying to make it so that a block of text of a file (`conf.py`) in each subdirectory (stored in the variable `SUBDIRS`) is deleted. This block of text is lies within the tags `#--Begin` and `#--End`. See code sample below. For the sake of being neat and not having to make an extra shell script to run from within the makefile, I'd like to use a sed command from within the makefile, but am having trouble doing so. I cannot find the solution to this on any other forum post, so any help would be gratefully received.

```
.PHONY $(SUBDIRS)
SUBDIRS = (list of all subdirectories that contain a relevant conf.py)
$(SUBDIRS):  
    sed '/#--Begin/,/#--End/d' Docs/$@/conf.py
```

Nothing happens as a result of this command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have tested the `sed` command on the command line before incorporating it into a makefile. As written it removes the lines you want it to remove-- and then directs the results to stdout. To modify the files in place you should use `-i`:

```
sed -i -e '/#--Begin/,/#--End/d' Docs/$@/conf.py
```

There may well be other problems. You haven't shown us the real makefile (`.PHONY $(SUBDIRS)` is not legal, so you're not pasting part a working makefile), but it's possible that the rule isn't even executing the way you think it should. Try this:

```
$(SUBDIRS):
    @echo attempting to act on $@
    @ls Docs/$@/conf.py
```

Get this to work *perfectly* before attempting to introduce the `sed` command.

Comment: Thanks. That's frustrating. Adding the -i option was all that was needed

Answer (score 5):

Your rule uses the SUBDIRS list for its targets. Make has a look to see if these exist, which of course they do. They do not depend on anything else, so they are up to date, so Make does not need to do anything.

There are two ways round this. One is to use a [Phony Target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets)
 to force the command to run every time:

```
.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
    sed .....
```

The other is to give the edited and unedited versions of the files different names, e.g.  `conf.py` and `conf.py.in`, and make the first depend on the second using a [Pattern Rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
$(SUBDIRS): Docs/%/conf.py: Docs/%/conf.py.in
   sed '/#--Begin/,/#--End/d' $< >$@
```

This is better, because it will run automatically whenever the input files change.

Comment: Apologies for not including `.PHONY` in the first place. I did in fact already have this before posting. The question has been updated to include this